# How to Identify Disk Location on ESXi?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

I have a VMWare ESXi 6.5 installed, and this ESXi is managed by vCenter. I recently need to replace some HDD to SSD, but I am not sure how to "blink" the disk so that I can pull it out safely.

---

Update

I'm using the HP server, I can access ILO. However, the problem is how to locate the datastore that is exactly the correct physical disk location in the server? In a datastore, the disk is represented as a serial number, such as `/vmfs/volumes/5dec23def-12dabf33881-29a0-00214dda8`

How to find the mapping relationship with my physical location?

Comment: What's the vendor of the hardware?

Comment: It's an old HP ML350 server

Answer (score 4):

What is the server vendor? You can use its own manager like IDRAC for Dell or ILO for HP. That would be much easier rather than trying to do this in ESXi.

Comment: I've updated my question, thanks